# Why are running records not set when running barefoot?

Tags: running, running-shoes, barefoot

When running records are set in areas with controlled conditions (e.g. nothing on the ground that could cause problems if barefoot), the runners still wear shoes.

It seems a curious idea that you run faster with shoes on than without, given the increase in weight on your feet.

– The theoretical  part of the question: Is there any evidence that running in lightweight shoes is faster than running barefoot?

– The practical part of the question: Why are (seemingly) no running records set with people running barefoot?

Please provide links to evidence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of/ couldn't find any studies on affecting performance. This study from 2014 states that no studies on performance have not been done on a wide scale. 
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268631549_The_Effect_of_Footwear_on_Running_Performance_and_Running_Economy_in_Distance_Runners

A quote from this meta-analysis:

> The reason that the mass of a light shoe (\440 g per pair) does not
>   have detrimental effects on running economy relative to barefoot, and
>   may even improve running economy, remains untested. It would seem likely
>   that, for footwear weighing less than 440g per pair, any disadvantage
>   due to having to repeatedly accelerate and decelerate the shoe
>   against gravity might bebalanced by the beneﬁcial effects on running
>   economy derived from the shoe cushioning [15], stiffness [12]
>   and comfort [10].

However as a speculation i would say that long distance running shoes provide a 'spring' that bare feet would not.

As for speculation sprinting shoes, they have grips on them which in theory would allow a sprinter to generate more force per stride. However this study says there is not a significant performance increase from barefoot to spiked shoes.

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/285212152_Evaluation_of_sprinting_performance_in_adolescent_athletes_with_running_shoes_spikes_and_barefoot